# Spring Boot buildInfo is causing Groovy Source Set be not "up-to-date" all the time

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy

in our project we are working with

```
springBoot 2.2.11
groovy 2.5.6
```

Our build.gradle looks like the following:

```
...
plugins {
  id 'groovy'
  id 'java'
  id 'idea'
}
configurations {
  testCompile.extendsFrom compile
  testRuntime.extendsFrom runtime
  ...
}
...
sourceSets {
  test {
    java { srcDirs = ['src/test/java'] }
    groovy {srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy'] }
  }
  ...
}
...
springBoot {
  buildInfo()
}
...
```

When we run `gradlew test --info` we get the following output:

```
...
> Task :bootBuildInfo
Caching disabled for task ':bootBuildInfo' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':bootBuildInfo' is not up-to-date because:
  Value of input property 'properties.time' has changed for task ':bootBuildInfo'
...
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
...
Skipping task ':compileJava' as it is up-to-date.
...
> Task :compileTestGroovy
Caching disabled for task ':compileTestGroovy' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileTestGroovy' is not up-to-date because:
  Input property 'astTransformationClasspath' file C:\projects\test-project\build\resources\main\META-INF\build-info.properties has changed.
The input changes require a full rebuild for incremental task ':compileTestGroovy'.
...
```

The build-info.properties file which is generated by spring-boots buildInfo step contains a `build.time` property which is updated on every execution.
The Java Compiler excludes this file apperently as the up-to-date check for `:compileJava` is returning true. However, the `compileGroovy` tasks includes this file into his sourceSet which is why it returns false on the up-to-date check.

I already tried the `exclude` option as follows with no success.

```
sourceSets {
  test {
    java { srcDirs = ['src/test/java'] }
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy']
      excludes = [file("${buildDir}/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties")]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Idealy I would like to exclude the file `build\resources\main\META-INF\build-info.properties` from the up-to-date-check (or even the input sourceSet of compileGroovy).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make spring-boot.properties generated with no time part(what makes springBoot task out of dated what in turn leads compileJava outdated)

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo {
        properties {
            // to make compileJava up to date
            // https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integrating-with-actuator.build-info
            time = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With recent spring boot versions 'excludes' should be used instead:
 `springBoot { buildInfo {  excludes = ['time'] } }`